# jQuery events stop working after partial view post in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View with a partial view.
In view, there are two inputs and one submit input that add display name and URL address to database. In partial view, I have table that lists existing URLs with submit input that deletes URLs. I don't have problem with adding, but when I want to delete a URL, delete event in jQuery works just once after posting page. When I hit the delete button, delete event doesn't work and it goes to add event.
What should I do?

This is my view:

```
<diventer code here class="page-header clearfix">
    <div class="page-header-inner clearfix">
        <div class="page-title">
            <h2>text</h2>
            <div class="page-title-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <p><a href="~/Home/Index">text</a> &#187;text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSiteUrl", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myform" }))
{
    Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
    <div class="content-wrapper page-content-wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="main-content page-content">

            <div class="inner-content-wrapper">

                <div class="course-finder-full clearfix">

                    <div class="course-finder-icon"></div>
                    <div class="course-finder-full-form">
                        <div>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SiteUrl.Name, new { @placeholder = "text", style = "width: 150px;" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SiteUrl.LinkAddress, new { @placeholder = "text" })
                            <input type="submit" value="name" name="btn.Add" id="btn_add" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 20px" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteUrl.Name)
                            <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteUrl.LinkAddress)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div_urllist">
                    @Html.Partial("_SitUrlList", Model.SiteUrls)

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-right page-content">

            <div class="content-block">
            </div>

            <div class="content-block">

            </div>
            <div class="">

                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

this is Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("fuc");
        $("#btn_add").click(function (e) {
            alert("add");
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Admin/AddSiteUrl",
                    data: $('#myform').serialize(),
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "Json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Success) {
                            $("#div_urllist").html(result.Html);
                        }
                        eval(result.Script);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("text");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //------------------------------------------------------
        $('.delurl').on('click', function (e) {
            alert("del");
        }).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/DeletesiteUrl",
                data: { Id: this.id },
                type: "Post",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Success) {
                        $("#div_urllist").html(result.Html);
                    }
                    eval(result.Script);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("text")
                }

            });
        });
        //------------------------------------------------------
    });


</script>
```

and this is my partial view

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ردیف</th>
            <th>نام </th>
            <th>آدرس</th>
            <th>مدیریت</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @{
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="ID">@i</td>
                    <td data-title="Course Name">@item.Name</td>
                    <td data-title="Program">@item.LinkAddress</td>
                    <td data-title="Length">
                        <input type="submit" value="حذف" id="@item.Id" class="button1 rounded-button delurl" onclick="delurlfunction()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            i++;
        }
    }
</table>
```

delete event before post:

[image: it work :D]
and  this is after Ajax posting:

[image: it call modal form submit event D:]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your first paragraph with correct punctuations / sentences, so people can understand you easily. Good luck with you problem

Comment: Learn about [jQuery delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I  Could not solve it in way I want but I reload page  with Ajax  it work

Answer (score 0):

Make the input type of Delete button to 'button' instead of 'submit'.

Comment: That's a good point but then still no data would be send to server

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the `click` event handler to `.delurl` which is dynamically added by your partial view. What happens is that when you delete a URL, you replace (destroy and re-generate) the content of `#div_urllist`. This means any event previously attached to elements in `#div_urllist` are also removed, so your click event handler is no longer attached on an event and is therefore no longer run.

You can instead attach the click handler to the static parent element `#div_urllist`, and tell `on()` to only run the handler on `.delurl` like this. Also note that you should remove the `.click(...)` as it is redundant.

```
$('#div_urllist').on('click', '.delurl', function (e) {
      alert("del");
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax(...);
});
```

For more info on how the above syntax, see [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).